# How do I calculate time complexity of these permutation and combination algorithms?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, combinations, permutation

Given the following functions, I need to determine the algorithmic complexity of `Permutations` and `Combinations`. The functions compute the number of possible permutations and combinations respectively, of any two given numbers `(n,r)`.

I think it could be `O(n!)` for the `Permutations` function but I'm wondering if it becomes something more like `O(log n!)` because in the return statement I'm dividing `n!` by `(n-r)!`.

```py
def factorial(x):
  if x < 2:
    return 1
  else:
    return x * factorial(x-1)

def Permutations(n, r):
  if r > n:
    return 0
  elif n == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return int(factorial(n) / factorial(n - r))

def Combinations(n,r):
  if r > n:
    return 0
  elif n == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return int((factorial(n) / factorial(n-r)) / factorial(r))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the functions are `O(n)`. To determine this, consider the effect of calling `Permutations(n,r)` for any non-trivial case (e.g. `(5,3)`):

Since `n > r and n != 0` the program execution will continue at

```py
  return int(factorial(n) / factorial(n-r))
```

Given the definition for `factorial` we can see that it is a simple recursion bounded by `n`. So we have that `factorial` is `O(n)`, from which we can prove `int(factorial(n) / factorial(n-r))` is `O(n + n)` which is still `O(n)`. This follows from the fact that execution must first compute `factorial(n)` in `O(n)` time, then compute `factorial(n-r)` in `O(n-r)` time. The other cases in `Permutations(n,r)` are `O(1)` so in the worst case this function is `O(n)`

Using similar reasoning, it can be concluded that `Combinations(n,r)` is `O(n + n + n)` which is also `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks Chad, your answer was very clear and easy to follow. Much appreciated!